# react js with redux, my container isn't receiving data after success actions / reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am a bit confuse. So I started react 2 weeks ago and redux recently (still in learning), I decided to have a go.

So I am just trying to make an API fetch and display the list.

Then I am quite proud, from **my container**:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

import { fetchPosts, invalidateReq } from '../actions/ajaxactions';
import DisplayWikiList from '../components/trending';
import DisplayBroadmatchList from '../components/trending';
import ColumnName from '../components/trending';
import DisplayOutPut from '../components/trending';

var Redux = require('redux');
var ReactRedux = require('react-redux');
var Card = require('material-ui/lib/card/card');

const { connect } = ReactRedux;


export default class DisplayTrendings extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(fetchPosts('trendings'));
    document.title = 'Blippar-wise Trendings - Blippar Dashboard';
  }

  render() {
    const { posts, isFetching } = this.props;
    console.log("posts :", posts);
    const isEmpty = posts.length === 0;
    return (
      <Card className="card-main">
          <h2 className="trending-title">Trendings</h2>
          <ColumnName />

          {isEmpty
            ? (isFetching ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : <h2>Empty request.</h2>)
            : <div className="col-md-6">
                <DisplayWikiList style={{ opacity: isFetching ? 0.5 : 1 }} posts={posts} />
              </div>
          }

          <div className="col-md-6">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-6">
                <input type="text" className="bespoke-label" />
              </div>
              <DisplayOutPut />
            </div>
          </div>
      </Card>
    );
  }
};

DisplayTrendings.propTypes = {
  posts: PropTypes.array,
  isFetching: PropTypes.bool,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const {
    isFetching,
    items: posts
  } = {
    isFetching: true,
    items: []
  }
  return {
    posts,
    isFetching
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DisplayTrendings)
```

I have the flow going perfectly through **my actions**:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

var Config = require('../configuration/config');

export const REQUEST_POSTS = 'REQUEST_POSTS'
export const RECEIVE_POSTS = 'RECEIVE_POSTS'
export const INVALIDATE_REQ = 'INVALIDATE_REQ'

export function invalidateReq(value) {
  return {
    type: INVALIDATE_REQ,
    value
  };
};

function requestPosts(value) {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_POSTS,
    value
  };
};

function receivePosts(json) {
    return {
        type: RECEIVE_POSTS,
        posts: json
    };
};

export function fetchPosts(value) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestPosts(value));
        return fetch(Config.serverUrl + '/' + value, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: Config.authorizationToken
            },
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(json)))
    };
};
```

and then it's correctly dispatch to **my reducers** !

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {
  INVALIDATE_REQ,
  REQUEST_POSTS, RECEIVE_POSTS
} from '../actions/ajaxactions'

function posts(state = {
  isFetching: false,
  didInvalidate: false,
  items: []
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_REQ:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            didInvalidate: true
        });
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: true,
            didInvalidate: false
        });
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: false,
            didInvalidate: false,
            items: action.posts
        });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    posts
});

export default rootReducer;
```

YES! Super! (Let me add that I checked all of it with some very smart console.logs)

But then, my page is freeze on "isFetching" (loading) and when I check the value "posts" on my container, it's definitely empty :(

Can someone help me **doing the connexion between the redux flow and then my container**?
Or **am I doing something terribly wrong in this code**?

Many thanks guys!

Edit: this is what I have in the console when I load my page:

[image]

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk? If not, you should be. As a side note, remove that last line from your question (re: guys / girls) it may be considered rude to some - as you said you never know

Comment: I am using redux-thunk in my store!

Comment: Interesting, hard to track in your code - could you show a dump from the redux dev tools in chrome or similar?

Comment: Thx for your answer, I just updated my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a week break from this refacto project, I was able to figure out the problem.

When elements are changing, reactJs gravite around the `state` property, which I wasn't using this whole time...

So, thx to Chris who wrote a first answer, I was able to figure out the problem.

Instead of writing:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const {
    isFetching,
    items: posts
  } = {
    isFetching: true,
    items: []
  }
  return {
    posts,
    isFetching
  };
};
```

Which was quite weird now I think of it, I switch for the state solution, which was just in front of me this whole time:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log("state: ", state);
  const {
    isFetching,
    items: posts
  } = {
    isFetching: state.posts.isFetching,
    items: state.posts.items
  }
  return {
    posts,
    isFetching
  };
};
```

And it works! Wuhuuu!

Answer (score 1):

In your container, you are setting `isFetching` to true, so it will *always* be true.

It appears you are perhaps trying to set default state, but this wouldn't be the place for that.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const {
    isFetching,
    items: posts
  } = {
    isFetching: true, // <-- this will always be true
    items: []
  }
  return {
    posts,
    isFetching
  };
};
```